# cakedc cvsimport plugin getimporterrors

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakedc

i got this error when trying to use cvdimport behaviour in cakedc utils plugin .

Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'getImportErrors' at line 1

**here is the import function**

```
function import() {
$modelClass = $this->modelClass;
 if( $this->request->is('POST')) {
    $records_count = $this->$modelClass->find('count');
    try {
        $this->$modelClass->importCSV($this->request->data[$modelClass]['CsvFile']['tmp_name']);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $import_errors = $this->$modelClass->getImportErrors();
        $this->set('import_errors', $import_errors);
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Error Importing')."  ".$this->request->data[$modelClass]['CsvFile']['name'] ." ," . __('column name mismatch.'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'import'));
   }
   $new_records_count = $this->$modelClass->find('count') - $records_count;
   $this->Session->setFlash(__('Successfully Imported') . "  " . $new_records_count . 'records from' . $this->request->data[$modelClass]['CvsFile']['name']);
   $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
$this->set('modelClass',$modelClass);
$this->render('../Common/import');
}//end import
```

**and the view file located in a common directory**

```
<h3>Import <?php echo Inflector::pluralize($modelClass); ?> from CSV data file</h3>
 <?php 
   echo $this->Form->create($modelClass, array('action' => 'import', 'type' => 'file'));
   echo $this->Form->input('CsvFile', array('label' => '', 'type' => 'file'));
   echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
```

?>

**the line with the error is this:** 
$import_errors = $this->$modelClass->getImportErrors();

can someone point out to me what is causing the error. i have no idea what to change to make it work

Answer (score 0):

When you get a SQL error for a method call on a model this usually means the behavior is not loaded. Figure out why.